# Insert in bulk using Sequelize with Node and Express

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Looking for a way to insert activities to the database in bulk using Sequelize `Model.bulkCreate`.

Not sure how to bring the activities from the view to the route function in order to insert them using `bulkCreate`. Right now I only insert one activity.

View:

```
<form action="/create" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Plan Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="plan_name" placeholder="Plan Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Activity</label>
    <input type="text" name="activity_name" placeholder="Activity">
    <label>Comment</label>
    <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Comment">
    <input type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="new">
  </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#add').click(function() {
    let activity = $('<div class="form-group"><label>Activity</label><input type="text" name="activity_name" placeholder="Activity"><label>Comment</label><input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Comment"></div>');
    $('#new').append(activity);
  });
</script>
```

Route:

```
  app.post('/create', (req, res) => {
    const user_id = req.user.id;
    const data = {
      plan_name: req.body.plan_name,
      description: req.body.description,
      userId: user_id
    };
    PlanModel.Plan.create(data).then(plan => {
      const activity = {
        activity_name: req.body.activity_name,
        comment: req.body.comment,
        plans_id: plan.id
      };
      ActivityModel.Activity.create(activity);
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Make fields to have names like an array

```
<div class="activities">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Activity</label>
    <input type="text" name="activities[0][name]" placeholder="Activity">
    <label>Comment</label>
    <input type="text" name="activities[0][comment]" placeholder="Comment">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Activity</label>
    <input type="text" name="activities[1][name]" placeholder="Activity">
    <label>Comment</label>
    <input type="text" name="activities[1][comment]" placeholder="Comment">
  </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group>
  <input type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">
</div>
```

2) At server-side just take that `req.body.activities` and generate array of objects and call `bulkCreate`

```
app.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = {
      plan_name: req.body.plan_name,
      description: req.body.description,
      userId: req.user.id
    };
    const plan = await PlanModel.Plan.create(data);


    if (req.body.activities && Array.isArray(req.body.activities)) {
      const activities = req.body.activities.map(
        activity => {
          return {
            activity_name: activity.name,
            comment: activity.comment,
            plans_id: plan.id
          }
        });
      await ActivityModel.Activity.bulkCreate(activities);
    }

    res.redirect('/');
  }
  catch(error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

3) Since body parser for urlencoded mode has extended option that parses deeply all of the fields. You've to enable it.
   **MAKE SURE** that **bodyParser** middleware attached with `extended: true` :

```
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: The code runs only up until  `const plan = await PlanModel.Plan.create(data);`. Only the plan gets inserted, code to insert activities doesnt run. No errors though.

Comment: @Supreme_B do: `console.log(req.body)` and see logs

Comment: Getting all the data, plan and activities with comments in the console log.

Comment: @Supreme_B please add that log to somewhere and share with me