# Multiple insert from hbs to MySQL express js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have this hbs code:

```
                    {{#each data2}}

                    <tr>                                                     
                      <td width="30%"><div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="data_{{no}}" id="id_produk" value=" {{no}}">{{item}}</label>
                      </div></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td width="30%"><div>
                        <label><input type="text" id="id_produk" name="data_{{no}}" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="Qty"></label>
                      </div></td>                         
                    </tr>

                    {{/each}}
```

and this router code:

```
router.post('/save', (req, res, next) => {
    var sql = "INSERT INTO transaction (transaction_id, product_id, qty) VALUES ?";
});
```

I want to submit multiple data to mysql database. How can i achive that ?

Comment: You can use the batch insert like : INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9); or refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899802/how-do-i-do-a-bulk-insert-in-mysql-using-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a duplicate question ref : [Insert in bulk using Sequelize with Node and Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358641/insert-in-bulk-using-sequelize-with-node-and-express)

Pass the data in an array , read the array and do bulk create operation

```
insert into (cols1, col2) values (list1val, list1val2), (list2val, list2val2)
```

Form data : 
 data_4: [ '4', '9' ], data_5: [ '5', '8' ], data_6: [ '6', '7' ], data_7: [ '7', '3' ], data_8: [ '8', '2' ], data_9: [ '9', '1' ]

```
    var responseObj = {data_4: [ '4', '9' ], data_5: [ '5', '8' ], data_6: [ '6', '7' ], data_7: [ '7', '3' ], data_8: [ '8', '2' ], data_9: [ '9', '1' ] };

var tblSQL = "insert into tbl (col1, col2) values ";
var sql;
for (let key in responseObj) {
   if(responseObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     console.log(`${key} : ${responseObj[key]}`)
     let id = responseObj[key][0];
     let age = responseObj[key][1];
     sql = (sql!=undefined ? sql+ "," : "") + "(" + id + "," + age+ ")";
   }
}

console.log (tblSQL  + sql);
```

Comment: yes, i have to pass the data in array. but how can i read the data in the route, and attach in the query SQL. I was try to get the console.log(req.body) and here ins the result:                                                                                                                
  data_4: [ '4', '9' ],
  data_5: [ '5', '8' ],
  data_6: [ '6', '7' ],
  data_7: [ '7', '3' ],
  data_8: [ '8', '2' ],
  data_9: [ '9', '1' ]

Comment: Ref : how to iterate the objects https://dev.to/saigowthamr/how-to-loop-through-object-in-javascript-es6-3d26 and then form a string contains key, values . example see the edited answer

Comment: i have tried your code. but there is an error that showing in my browser page. The error is: "responseObj.hasOwnProperty is not a function". what error is that? and how do i fix it?

Comment: check how you are passing the data in jquery / javascript to the node js layer. You should properly convert into JSON object and send it to the node layer during form submission or read the form submitted data and generate a Javascritp object in this format  var responseObj = {data_4: [ '4', '9' ], data_5: [ '5', '8' ], data_6: [ '6', '7' ], data_7: [ '7', '3' ], data_8: [ '8', '2' ], data_9: [ '9', '1' ] };

Comment: thank you for your help. I got the the clue from your link you shared to me. And this is my code:                                          
                                                                              
          Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
            var a = (sql + "(" + `${obj[key]}`);
            console.log(a);
            connection.query(a, function(err, rows1) {});
        });      and it works,,,

Comment: great, if you find it useful.. kindlly mark it as correct answer